# Why my cookies are not saving?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with cookies. In my login script i have the following line of code:

```
if($_GET['keep'] == "true"){
            setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600);


        }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the cookies are not saving at all ( not even if i don't quit the browser). I'm quite a beginer in this respect and I think I'm not doing it right.

EDIT:
If i `print_r` all the Cookies it only gives me PHPSESSID after the cookie is set. I printed on index.php and i set the cookie on login.php

SOLUTION: Cookies are saved by default with the path of the file they were created in. To change the path there is another atribute. So by `setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600,'/');` you make the cookie available for the entire domain.

Comment: There is another issue too, that = should be ==

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - I think this won't cause the issue. This will be always true.

Comment: `not saving if I exit the browser` suppose you are not quitting the browser does it keep the cookie...? just dump `$_COOKIE` after setting it. so that you can make sure that `setcookie` is working

Comment: Are you sure it should be `"true"` and not `true`? They are not the same thing.

Comment: If is not work after all, you should check your browser, does it set to clean all cookies when you quit.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal that is why i said ***another issue too***

Comment: Does other cookies save in the same browser?

Comment: yes.. I think... facebook keep me login is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no issue** in your code

```
if($_GET['keep'] = "true"){
   setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600);
}
```

---

**This will may cause to**

1. ***No data passing*** to `$_GET['keep']`
2. Or if data passing `$_GET['keep']` ***value in not Matched*** ("true").
3. Both Works ***then `$id` is empty*** in `setcookie` method

---

**Improve your code**

```
if(isset($_GET['keep']){

    if($_GET['keep'] == "true"){
        if(isset($id))
        {
            #all perpect
            $cokkie_id = 'id';
            setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600);

            echo "I'm Set. And My value is ".$cokkie_id;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Opzz My ID is also empty";
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Get method is Set. But Value is not "true". Actual value is '. $_GET['keep'];
    }   
}
else
{
    echo 'I cant reach Get method Buddy';
}
```

Comment: I tried this debuging method, and the method is set with the value true

Comment: try all of my code. then you will get know whats wrong.

Comment: $id is set. i can echo it and it shows 0, the id of the row i`m fetching from the database

Comment: use mine. and post the error. Not ur own echos. try it first

Comment: shows I`m set. I should check other browsers? I`m using chrome

Comment: your cookies is set. Why do you need error? I don't understand.

Comment: Are using incognito mode browser?

Comment: @BogdanConstantin checked ??

Comment: i get "I'm Set. And My value is id" I suppose it is ok

Comment: the script that is setting the cookie is ran by ajax... Is that the problem?

Comment: place this all inside that. so that you can get idea about whats wrong. And this code haven't any bit of error.

Comment: solved the problem by setting the path of the cookie. 
 setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600,'/');

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss "=" sign

```
if ($_GET['keep'] == "true") {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['id'])) {
         setcookie('id',$id,time()+3153600);
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but that would not prevent the cookie from saving. It would make it save the cookie every single time.

Comment: If this solution solves your problem, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: You don't have to prompt people to do stuff. If they find it useful then they will upvote/accept it in their own time.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Some people out there, once they get the working solution, they will leave it, they won't bother to mark it correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` or `==`

```
if (isset($_GET['keep']) && $_GET['keep'] == "true") {
    setcookie('id', $id,time()+3153600);
}else{
    echo 'keep is empty';
}
```